# Why can't I use sort or orderby on DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I try to sort a DataFrame:

```
val df1 = df.toDF().sort(desc("sourceId"))
```

I get:

> 17/11/07 15:15:37 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 114.0 (TID 218)
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: scala.math.Ordering$$anon$4
>   Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(scala.math.Ordering$$anon$4.class);
>   Serialization trace:
>   ord (org.apache.spark.util.BoundedPriorityQueue)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:101)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
>       at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.write(SomeSerializer.scala:21)
>       at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.write(SomeSerializer.scala:19)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serialize(KryoSerializer.scala:312)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:364)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: scala.math.Ordering$$anon$4

I've also tried order by, but neither works.

What is the issue here? Do I have to import ordering
`scala.math.order`?

Comment: @MaxU dont think its duplicate, the error wasn't present in the other question

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._; val df1 = df.orderBy(desc("sourceId"))` - does that work?

Comment: @MaxU unfortunately, same problem

Comment: can you provide a reproducible sample data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using `spark.kryo.registrationRequired`

```
spark.kryo.registrationRequired  true
```

Please either set it to `false`:

```
spark.kryo.registrationRequired  false
```

or add required class to `spark.kryo.classesToRegister`